# error with cast(reshape), can't find column variable, long to wide

Tags: r, casting, reshape

I have used the cast function before with no issues.
I am having trouble with this recent dataset.
I get this:

```
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `lambs` doesn't exist."
```

It is a generated variable that I am then trying to use to cast the whole dataset wide so I can merge with another dataset on individual ewe numbers.

This was what I wrote:

```
birthwide<-cast(births, ewe~lambs)
```

If I give you a small subset of data like this:

```
births<-data.frame(ewe = c(467993,50182754,50182754,50247299), 
lambs = c("Lamb1", "Lamb1","Lamb2", "Lamb1"),lid=c(213075, 212479, 231779,228837))
```

it works, but I am not understanding why it is not reading the variable I have....
I have tried all variations of quotes incl. back ticks and other made up data and it works. There is something wrong with how I set up this variable that it is not "seeing" it.

I can summary(births$lambs) and table(births$lambs) with no problem...

Data structure:

```
structure(list(ewe = c(467993, 1239411, 2425980, 2426785, 
50182754, 50182754, 50247299, 99999999, 99999999, 317023062), 
    lid = c(213075, 230520, 562412, 563106, 212479, 231779, 
    563100, 213013, 229223, 229952), lambs = c("Lamb1", "Lamb1", 
    "Lamb1", "Lamb1", "Lamb1", "Lamb2", "Lamb1", "Lamb1", "Lamb2", 
    "Lamb1")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Stumped.

Thanks!
CB

Comment: If it works with the sample you provide here, how can we replicate your problem? Clearly there must be a problem with your data, but we don't have that. Can you perhaps post a small sample of your real data? Try `dput(head(births, 10))`. Also, you might want to check `names(births)` since if there is a trailing white space in the name of the column, such as `"lambs "` rather than `"lambs"`, the behaviour you report would be expected.

Comment: Thanks Allan, that was silly of me, I checked names no spaces, here is my data structure:

Answer (score 0):

Here, `cast` assumes that you want `lambs` as the value column, so it is no longer available as a variable to recast by. Presumably you wanted the value to come from the "lid" column:

```r
reshape::cast(births, ewe ~ lambs, value = "lid")
        ewe  Lamb1  Lamb2
1    467993 213075     NA
2   1239411 230520     NA
3   2425980 562412     NA
4   2426785 563106     NA
5  50182754 212479 231779
6  50247299 563100     NA
7  99999999 213013 229223
8 317023062 229952     NA
```

Comment: Thanks Alan I appreciate the help. Can I ask why if I use library(reshape) and then births_wide<-cast(births, ewe ~ lambs, value = "lid") I still get an error but if I do exactly what you wrote it does not.....?